# Links with javascript only show one at a time

Tags: javascript, html

I am completely new to this and I would like to know how I can make it so that when you click on one of the links only the text relating to that link is shown. So, for example, if I click Kabling and then Programmering the text about Kabling should not be displayed. I would really appreciate any feedback on everything else as well since I just started to learn HTML and CSS 3 weeks ago. To be able to post this question I need to write more text although I'm not sure what to write.

Thank you in advance

````
<html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Andreas</title>

    <!-- styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stil.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    

    <div class="menu">
      <div class="label">menu</div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
    <!-- Knappar -->
      <!-- Kabling -->
      
      <div class="item"><a onclick="myFunction1()" href="javascript:void(0);">Kabling</a></div>
      <!-- Programmering -->
      <div class="item"><a onclick="myFunction2()" href="javascript:void(0);">Programmering</a></div>
      <!-- Konvertering -->
      <div class="item"><a onclick="myFunction3()" href="javascript:void(0);">Konvertering</a></div>
      <!-- Bildbehandling -->
      <div class="item"><a onclick="myFunction4()" href="javascript:void(0);">Bildbehandling</a></div>
      <!-- Chrome devtools -->
      <div class="item"><a onclick="myFunction5()" href="javascript:void(0);">Chrome Devtools</a></div>
      <!-- Ellära -->
      <div class="item"><a onclick="myFunction6()" href="javascript:void(0);">Ellära</a></div>
      <!--  -->
      


<img src="" alt="">
</div>

    <!-- Content -->

    <!-- Kabling Text -->
    <br>          
    <div id="KablingText"style="display:none;">
      <font size="+3">Sette opp nettverk</font>
     <br><br>
     <img class="subjimg" src="images/kabling.jpg">
     <div class="subjtxt">Trekke kabler i veggkanal å sette på ethernetkontakt på kat 6 kabel.
     Hva et patchpanel, svitj og etasjefordeler er. Anext (elektromagnetisk støy), Separasjon mellom starkstrømkabel og tele/datakabel SxP=A.Nek 700 regelbok
     Cenelec Ekomloven. Strukturert kabling Fiber Potens Likstrøm og væxelstrøm Sinuskurva.
     Diagonalrevolvert kabel. Slaglengde.Bølgelengde λ Multiplikatorer – atto – exa I=Strøm, Itensitè courant
    </div>       
    </div>

    <!-- Programmering Text -->
    
    <div id="Programmering"style="display:none;">
      <h2>Om programmering</h2>
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa porro ducimus animi! Nisi, temporibus? Iure, doloremque quisquam eveniet, nesciunt, unde culpa recusandae inventore voluptates ipsum esse veritatis eius magni rem?
    </div>
    
    <!-- Konvertering Text -->

    <div id="Konvertering"style="display:none;">
      Binære tall og hvordan man regner med dem. Mega=miljon=1x106
      Giga=miljard=1x109. Hz svingninger pes sek, Høy frekvens har dårligere rekkevidde lav frekvens har bedre rekkevidde.
      
    </div>

    <!-- Bildbehandling Text -->
    
    <div id="Bildbehandling"style="display:none;">
      Text om Bildbehandling
    </div>
    
    <!-- Chrome Devtools Text -->
    
    <div id="ChromeDevtools"style="display:none;">
      Text om Chrome Devtools
    </div>

     <!-- Ellära Text -->

     <div id="Ellära"style="display:none;">
      Text om Ellära
    </div>
</div>
 
<!--JS För knapp 1  -->

<script>
  function myFunction1() {
      var x = document.getElementById('KablingText');
      if (x.style.display === 'none') {
          x.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
          x.style.display = 'none';
      }
  }
  </script>
  
  <!--JS För knapp 2  -->
  
  <script>
    function myFunction2() {
        var x = document.getElementById('Programmering');
        if (x.style.display === 'none') {
            x.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            x.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    </script>

    <!--JS För knapp 3  -->

    <script>
      function myFunction3() {
          var x = document.getElementById('Konvertering');
          if (x.style.display === 'none') {
              x.style.display = 'block';
          } else {
              x.style.display = 'none';
          }
      }
      </script>

    <!--JS För knapp 4  -->

    <script>
      function myFunction4() {
          var x = document.getElementById('Bildbehandling');
          if (x.style.display === 'none') {
              x.style.display = 'block';
          } else {
              x.style.display = 'none';
          }
      }
      </script>
    
    <!--JS För knapp 5  -->

    <script>
      function myFunction5() {
          var x = document.getElementById('ChromeDevtools');
          if (x.style.display === 'none') {
              x.style.display = 'block';
          } else {
              x.style.display = 'none';
          }
      }
      </script>

      <!--JS För knapp 6  -->

<script>
  function myFunction6() {
      var x = document.getElementById('Ellära');
      if (x.style.display === 'none') {
          x.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
          x.style.display = 'none';
      }
  }
  </script>


  </body
</html>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removed code duplication

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Andreas</title>

    <!-- styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stil.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="label">menu</div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <!-- Knappar -->
        <!-- Kabling -->

        <div class="item"><a onclick="myFunction('KablingText')" href="javascript:void(0);">Kabling</a></div>
        <!-- Programmering -->
        <div class="item"><a onclick="myFunction('Programmering')" href="javascript:void(0);">Programmering</a></div>
        <!-- Konvertering -->
        <div class="item"><a onclick="myFunction('Konvertering')" href="javascript:void(0);">Konvertering</a></div>
        <!-- Bildbehandling -->
        <div class="item"><a onclick="myFunction('Bildbehandling')" href="javascript:void(0);">Bildbehandling</a></div>
        <!-- Chrome devtools -->
        <div class="item"><a onclick="myFunction('ChromeDevtools')" href="javascript:void(0);">Chrome Devtools</a></div>
        <!-- Ellära -->
        <div class="item"><a onclick="myFunction('Ellära')" href="javascript:void(0);">Ellära</a></div>
        <!--  -->



        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>

    <!-- Content -->

    <!-- Kabling Text -->
    <br>
    <div id="KablingText" style="display:none;">
        <font size="+3">Sette opp nettverk</font>
        <br><br>
        <img class="subjimg" src="images/kabling.jpg">
        <div class="subjtxt">Trekke kabler i veggkanal å sette på ethernetkontakt på kat 6 kabel.
            Hva et patchpanel, svitj og etasjefordeler er. Anext (elektromagnetisk støy), Separasjon mellom
            starkstrømkabel og tele/datakabel SxP=A.Nek 700 regelbok
            Cenelec Ekomloven. Strukturert kabling Fiber Potens Likstrøm og væxelstrøm Sinuskurva.
            Diagonalrevolvert kabel. Slaglengde.Bølgelengde λ Multiplikatorer – atto – exa I=Strøm, Itensitè courant
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Programmering Text -->

    <div id="Programmering" style="display:none;">
        <h2>Om programmering</h2>
        <br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa porro ducimus animi! Nisi, temporibus? Iure,
        doloremque quisquam eveniet, nesciunt, unde culpa recusandae inventore voluptates ipsum esse veritatis eius
        magni rem?
    </div>

    <!-- Konvertering Text -->

    <div id="Konvertering" style="display:none;">
        Binære tall og hvordan man regner med dem. Mega=miljon=1x106
        Giga=miljard=1x109. Hz svingninger pes sek, Høy frekvens har dårligere rekkevidde lav frekvens har bedre
        rekkevidde.

    </div>

    <!-- Bildbehandling Text -->

    <div id="Bildbehandling" style="display:none;">
        Text om Bildbehandling
    </div>

    <!-- Chrome Devtools Text -->

    <div id="ChromeDevtools" style="display:none;">
        Text om Chrome Devtools
    </div>

    <!-- Ellära Text -->

    <div id="Ellära" style="display:none;">
        Text om Ellära
    </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var kabling = document.getElementById('KablingText');
        var prog = document.getElementById('Programmering');
        var konv = document.getElementById('Konvertering');
        var bild = document.getElementById('Bildbehandling');
        var chrome = document.getElementById('ChromeDevtools');
        var ell = document.getElementById('Ellära');

        var allEle = [kabling, prog, konv, bild, chrome, ell]

         function myFunction(id) {
            for (let index = 0; index < allEle.length; index++) {
                const element = allEle[index];
                if (element.id === id) {
                    if (element.style.display === 'none')
                        element.style.display = 'block';
                    else element.style.display = 'none';
                } else
                    element.style.display = "none"
            }

        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Welcome @user17319549, you already add logic which is good, only some more lines.

You can just simply hide others when you are showing one.

The below code is pure javascript, while below in jquery. Right now jquery is used in the industry very widely.

```js
var vkabling = document.getElementById('KablingText');
var vprog = document.getElementById('Programmering');
var vkonv = document.getElementById('Konvertering');
var vbild = document.getElementById('Bildbehandling');
var vchrome = document.getElementById('ChromeDevtools');
var vell = document.getElementById('Ellära');

//pMenuValue - parameter menu value
function ShowHideContents(pMenuValue) {
debugger;
    vkabling.style.display = 'none';
    vprog.style.display = 'none';
    vkonv.style.display = 'none';
    vbild.style.display = 'none';
    vchrome.style.display = 'none';
    vell.style.display = 'none';
      
   switch(pMenuValue) {        
        case 1:
            vkabling.style.display = 'block';
            break;
        case 2:
            vprog.style.display = 'block';
            break;
        case 3:
           vkonv.style.display = 'block';
            break;
        case 4:
            vbild.style.display = 'block';
            break;
        case 5:
            vchrome.style.display = 'block';
            break;
        case 6:
            vell.style.display = 'block';
            break;
     }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Andreas</title>

    <!-- styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stil.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    

    <div class="menu">
      <div class="label">menu</div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
    <!-- Knappar -->
      <!-- Kabling -->
      
      <div class="item"><a onclick="ShowHideContents(1)" href="javascript:void(0);">Kabling</a></div>
      <!-- Programmering -->
      <div class="item"><a onclick="ShowHideContents(2)" href="javascript:void(0);">Programmering</a></div>
      <!-- Konvertering -->
      <div class="item"><a onclick="ShowHideContents(3)" href="javascript:void(0);">Konvertering</a></div>
      <!-- Bildbehandling -->
      <div class="item"><a onclick="ShowHideContents(4)" href="javascript:void(0);">Bildbehandling</a></div>
      <!-- Chrome devtools -->
      <div class="item"><a onclick="ShowHideContents(5)" href="javascript:void(0);">Chrome Devtools</a></div>
      <!-- Ellära -->
      <div class="item"><a onclick="ShowHideContents(6)" href="javascript:void(0);">Ellära</a></div>
      <!--  -->

<img src="" alt="">
</div>
    <!-- Content -->
    <!-- Kabling Text -->
    <br>          
    <div id="KablingText"style="display:none;">
      <font size="+3">Sette opp nettverk</font>
     <br><br>
     <img class="subjimg" src="images/kabling.jpg">
     <div class="subjtxt">Trekke kabler i veggkanal å sette på ethernetkontakt på kat 6 kabel.
     Hva et patchpanel, svitj og etasjefordeler er. Anext (elektromagnetisk støy), Separasjon mellom starkstrømkabel og tele/datakabel SxP=A.Nek 700 regelbok
     Cenelec Ekomloven. Strukturert kabling Fiber Potens Likstrøm og væxelstrøm Sinuskurva.
     Diagonalrevolvert kabel. Slaglengde.Bølgelengde λ Multiplikatorer – atto – exa I=Strøm, Itensitè courant
    </div>       
    </div>

    <!-- Programmering Text -->
    
    <div id="Programmering"style="display:none;">
      <h2>Om programmering</h2>
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa porro ducimus animi! Nisi, temporibus? Iure, doloremque quisquam eveniet, nesciunt, unde culpa recusandae inventore voluptates ipsum esse veritatis eius magni rem?
    </div>
    
    <!-- Konvertering Text -->

    <div id="Konvertering"style="display:none;">
      Binære tall og hvordan man regner med dem. Mega=miljon=1x106
      Giga=miljard=1x109. Hz svingninger pes sek, Høy frekvens har dårligere rekkevidde lav frekvens har bedre rekkevidde.
      
    </div>

    <!-- Bildbehandling Text -->
    
    <div id="Bildbehandling"style="display:none;">
      Text om Bildbehandling
    </div>
    
    <!-- Chrome Devtools Text -->
    
    <div id="ChromeDevtools"style="display:none;">
      Text om Chrome Devtools
    </div>

     <!-- Ellära Text -->

     <div id="Ellära"style="display:none;">
      Text om Ellära
    </div>
</div>
  </body
</html>
```

As you are at the learning stage, try to learn Jquery simultaneously as its very useful (https://jquery.com/ - jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. )

```js
var vkabling = $('#KablingText'); // document.getElementById('KablingText');
var vprog = $('#Programmering');//document.getElementById('Programmering');
var vkonv =$('#Konvertering');// document.getElementById('Konvertering');
var vbild = $('#Bildbehandling');//document.getElementById('Bildbehandling');
var vchrome = $('#ChromeDevtools');//document.getElementById('ChromeDevtools');
var vell = $('#Ellära');//document.getElementById('Ellära');

//pMenuValue - parameter menu value
function ShowHideContents(pMenuValue) {
debugger; //use debugger in javascript/jquery to debug the code

  //this is the same javascript code in jquery side, only use show/hide function of jquery
    vkabling.hide(); //vkabling.style.display = 'none';
    vprog.hide();    //vprog.style.display = 'none';
    vkonv.hide();    //vkonv.style.display = 'none';
    vbild.hide();    //vbild.style.display = 'none';
    vchrome.hide();  //vchrome.style.display = 'none';
    vell.hide();     //vell.style.display = 'none';
      
   switch(pMenuValue) {        
        case 1:
            vkabling.show();//vkabling.style.display = 'block';
            break;
        case 2:
            vprog.show();//vprog.style.display = 'block';
            break;
        case 3:
           vkonv.show();//vkonv.style.display = 'block';
            break;
        case 4:
            vbild.show();//vbild.style.display = 'block';
            break;
        case 5:
            vchrome.show();//vchrome.style.display = 'block';
            break;
        case 6:
            vell.show();//vell.style.display = 'block';
            break;
     }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Andreas</title>

    <!-- styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stil.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    

    <div class="menu">
      <div class="label">menu</div>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
    <!-- Knappar -->
      <!-- Kabling -->
      
      <div class="item"><a onclick="ShowHideContents(1)" href="javascript:void(0);">Kabling</a></div>
      <!-- Programmering -->
      <div class="item"><a onclick="ShowHideContents(2)" href="javascript:void(0);">Programmering</a></div>
      <!-- Konvertering -->
      <div class="item"><a onclick="ShowHideContents(3)" href="javascript:void(0);">Konvertering</a></div>
      <!-- Bildbehandling -->
      <div class="item"><a onclick="ShowHideContents(4)" href="javascript:void(0);">Bildbehandling</a></div>
      <!-- Chrome devtools -->
      <div class="item"><a onclick="ShowHideContents(5)" href="javascript:void(0);">Chrome Devtools</a></div>
      <!-- Ellära -->
      <div class="item"><a onclick="ShowHideContents(6)" href="javascript:void(0);">Ellära</a></div>
      <!--  -->

<img src="" alt="">
</div>
    <!-- Content -->
    <!-- Kabling Text -->
    <br>          
    <div id="KablingText"style="display:none;">
      <font size="+3">Sette opp nettverk</font>
     <br><br>
     <img class="subjimg" src="images/kabling.jpg">
     <div class="subjtxt">Trekke kabler i veggkanal å sette på ethernetkontakt på kat 6 kabel.
     Hva et patchpanel, svitj og etasjefordeler er. Anext (elektromagnetisk støy), Separasjon mellom starkstrømkabel og tele/datakabel SxP=A.Nek 700 regelbok
     Cenelec Ekomloven. Strukturert kabling Fiber Potens Likstrøm og væxelstrøm Sinuskurva.
     Diagonalrevolvert kabel. Slaglengde.Bølgelengde λ Multiplikatorer – atto – exa I=Strøm, Itensitè courant
    </div>       
    </div>

    <!-- Programmering Text -->
    
    <div id="Programmering"style="display:none;">
      <h2>Om programmering</h2>
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa porro ducimus animi! Nisi, temporibus? Iure, doloremque quisquam eveniet, nesciunt, unde culpa recusandae inventore voluptates ipsum esse veritatis eius magni rem?
    </div>
    
    <!-- Konvertering Text -->

    <div id="Konvertering"style="display:none;">
      Binære tall og hvordan man regner med dem. Mega=miljon=1x106
      Giga=miljard=1x109. Hz svingninger pes sek, Høy frekvens har dårligere rekkevidde lav frekvens har bedre rekkevidde.
      
    </div>

    <!-- Bildbehandling Text -->
    
    <div id="Bildbehandling"style="display:none;">
      Text om Bildbehandling
    </div>
    
    <!-- Chrome Devtools Text -->
    
    <div id="ChromeDevtools"style="display:none;">
      Text om Chrome Devtools
    </div>

     <!-- Ellära Text -->

     <div id="Ellära"style="display:none;">
      Text om Ellära
    </div>
</div>
  </body
</html>
```

Comment: there is an issue with code, if the div is already block then it doesn't switch to none.
also, jquery was used in the industry very widely. nowadays jquery is not used widely, bootstrap 5 has removed jquery dependency and use vanilla js

Comment: I already consider that, Just see in the code, first we hide all and then only show the current one which we passed as no parameter

Comment: are you check/test my the snippet

Comment: your code fails to handle 1 case as mentioned above. the bellow div should be hidden if the user clicks twice on the same anchor tag

Comment: Im not supposed to use the comments to say thank you. But I am so very grateful and happy for your help and the least I can do is to show it! The comments about jquery and bootstrap was also very helpful so a BIG thanks guys!

Comment: @HimanshuPatil, there is no comment for twice click, otherwise I was add there. For Andreas is a learner, I suggest that go first with Jquery and based on jquery you can learn other js. Right now there is so many different different js based on requirements like bootstrap, angular, vue, react, but need to first basic concept via javascript/jquery  combination.